# What is the best way to write a code in python to read some sample input from a "txt" files?

Tags: python, input, python-2.7

I know it's a very basic question but i am also a newbie in python environment. I am writing my first program (Data structure problem) where i need to read some input test cases.

Input:

```
The first line contains the number of test cases T. T test cases follow. 
The first line for each case contains N, the number of elements to be sorted. 
The next line contains N integers a[1],a[2]...,a[N].
```

Constraints:

```
1 <= T <= 5
1 <= N <= 100000
1 <= a[i] <= 1000000
```

Sample Input:

```
2
5
1 1 1 2 2
5
2 1 3 1 2
```

I wrote a following program to read the above input from a file but i am sure that this is not the best way to do it because it contains a lot of `if-else` loop and `for` loop which will really sucks at the large `inputs`.

```
sample = open('sample.txt')
first = sample.readline()
if len(first) > 5 or len(first) <1:
    print "Not correct input";
else:
    test = sample.readline
    for x in range(0,len(first)):
        second = sample.readline()
        if len(second) >100000 or len(second) < 1:
            print "wrong input";
        else:
            third = list()
            for y in range(0, len(third)):
                third.append(sample.readline()[:1])
        method_test(third)  #calling a method for each sample input
```

Please suggest me the best solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems that you have the reading part down, are you trying to constrain the input? Also, it looks like both of those `if`s are always going to fail (impossible to satisfy both and conditions). Which is to say, they will never print "Not correct input"/"wrong input".

Comment: Actually i just want to get the generic solution to read the sample input from a file with each constraints.

Comment: ``if len(first) > 5 and len(first) <1`` does not make sense. You probably mean ``or``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
with open('sample.txt') as sample:
    num_testcases = int(sample.readline())
    assert 1 <= num_testcases <= 5
    for testcase in range(num_testcases):
        num_elems = int(sample.readline())
        assert 1 <= num_elems <= 10000
        elems = map(int, sample.readline().split())
        assert len(elems) == num_elems
        assert all(1 <= elem <= 100000 for elem in elems)
        method_test(elems)
```

Edit: Added validity checks.

Comment: Very concise, and good job pointing out that the number of elements isn't even used. Maybe you should add a bit of text about your use of `int` vs `len` to make this the complete package? I think you are also not checking the OPs bounds on the elements.

Comment: i would probably add an `assert len(elems) == num_elems` but yeah good answer

Comment: How should i check the constraints?. I mean the third constraint?

Comment: @AmitPal: Was in the middle of adding the third constraint and my Internet connection when down for a few minutes -- OK now.

Comment: Yeh i got that and Thanks @martineau

Comment: `all(1 <= x <= 100000 for x in elems)` is a cleaner way of expressing that last one

Comment: @Eric: Good point...and probably a bit more memory efficient and maybe faster, too. I'll incorporate your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly. `len(x)` will tell you the length of the inputs, so if your input line is "9", `len(line)` will be 1; if your input line is "999", `len(line)` will be 3. You need to use `int(line)` to read a number from the input file correctly.

The logic of the rest of the program doesn't look right - for example, you are reading the first line (the number of tests), and looping over this number (which is fine) - but you are reading the number of values *outside* this loop, which is the wrong order.

I strongly recommend you print out the various values as you read them, so you can follow what is going on, and debug your program more easily.

Finally when you do the following:

```
        third = list()
        for y in range(0, len(third)):...
```

you are creating an empty list `list()` then looping from 0 to the length of the list (which is also zero). So the loop won't actually do anything.

Comment: Thanks for answering @DNA but would it possible for you write the solution. So that i can understand it

Comment: No, sorry - you need to work through this yourself in order to learn anything from it. I will add some more pointers in my answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

use `cycle()` to read only only alternate lines after the first line, and the size of cycle will be twice the value of `T`.

```
 from itertools import islice,cycle
 with open("data1.txt") as f:
    T = int(f.readline())
    if T != 0:
            cyc=islice(cycle((False,True)),T*2) 
            for x in cyc:
                if x or not f.readline():
                    print map(int,f.readline().split())
```

**output:**

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Way too complex of an answer to very basic question from a newbie, IMHO. [_Premature optimization is the root of all evil_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize), anyway. ;-)